# boto in py2app dies on initialization reading json file

Tags: python, boto, py2app

I've built a simple python/tkinter app to start and stop an AWS EC2 instance using the `boto` library. It works fine standalone and fine when built to a mac app using `py2app` with the `-A` (alias) option to use symbolic links rather than copying everything.

When boto starts up, it tries to read its region data from a file in the top level of the boto package called `endpoints.json`.

When I run the py2app-built executable, I get this message:

`3/24/16 8:22:17.860 PM MyApp[49220]: IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/me/src/ec2-app/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/boto/endpoints.json'`

Note that it's trying to read from a path that includes this zip file: `site-packages.zip`. If I look in that zip file, there is indeed a file `boto/endpoints.json`. It looks like `py2app` gathers all relevant site stuff into this zip file and expects code to read through that.

How do I get boto working from a py2app app?

Here's my `setup.py` file for py2app:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
APP_NAME = "MyApp"
DATA_FILES = []

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    py_modules=['instance', 'settings'],
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: I didn't solve this but did get my app working by switching from py2app to PyInstaller

Answer (score 0):

I met the similiar problem these days

```
<Notice>: IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/kawhi/Desktop/dpdb/dist/runserver.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/dpdb/templates/index.html'
```

I don't know why, but when I go to the path `runserver.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/`, find the zip file `site-packages.zip`, I did 3 steps.

1. I unzipped the `site-packages.zip`
2. I renamed the `site-packages.zip` as `site-packages.zip.bak`
3. I **renamed** the unzipped file `site-packages` to `site-packages.zip`

After that `/Users/kawhi/Desktop/dpdb/dist/runserver.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7//python2.7/site-packages.zip/dpdb/templates/index.html` was a directory. And my application worked.